# VBA doesn't export every cell from excel to PDF file

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I'm a bit confused. The export from an excel sheet to a pdf file actual works fine. but after I added a new sentence in bottom of the sheet, it doesn't copy this sentence in the pdf file. My excel sheet contains a form of 180 cells. In 181 is the new sentence but it won't take this in pdf.

Could anyone tell me what the problem is presumably?

If you need more information, I would try to give you some more details.

Edit:
The export is defined as follows:

```
Worksheets(NameSheet).ExportAsFixedFormat _
Type:=xlTypePDF, _
FileName:=File, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludedocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False
```

The sentence is added directly in excel sheet without vba code. I searched in the code for `.Cells(181,1)` but nothing was defined. That means for me, in the pdf the sentence should be generated.

Comment: what code are you using?

Comment: Maybe a [print area](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-or-clear-a-print-area-on-a-worksheet-2e5992fa-f201-41a1-9f39-370ff14deca1) is setted?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav What do you need exactly? See my edited post

Comment: @AxelRichter Look above. I setted `IgnorePrintAreas` to false

Comment: @yuro: *g* `IgnorePrintAreas:=False` means do not ignore print areas. But you need to ignore print areas, don't you?

Comment: @AxelRichter I'm looking for the definition of the PrintArea but it isn't defined anywhere for this sheet.. very strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out. That was a setting in excel.

the solution is described on this page: [Set a print area](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-or-clear-a-print-area-on-a-worksheet-2e5992fa-f201-41a1-9f39-370ff14deca1?omkt=en-US&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Description:

> 1. On the worksheet, select the cells that you want to define as the print area. (I selected all cells up to 181)
> 2. On the `Page Layout` tab, in the `Page Setup` group, click `Print Area`, and then click `Set Print Area`.

Comment: Gotta love it!  Machines do exactly what you tell them to do!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also manually set the print area if you want.

```
  With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .PrintArea = "$A$1:$AA$181"
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesTall = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
  End With
```